# What does a return type of class return?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class called `Practice.`

```
public class Practice 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        test x= new test();
        System.out.println(x.testFunction());
    }

}
```

And another class called `Test`

```
class Test 
{
    public Practice testFunction()
    {
        return xxxx;
    }
}
```

So since the return type is of class Practice, what could I replace xxxx with. Like suppose the return type is int, so I am supposed to return a number, when the return type is string, I am supposed to return a sentence. So when the return type is a class, what does it actually return.

Comment: You have to return an instance of the type `Practice` in that `testFunction()`, like `return new Practice();`, for example...

Comment: It will return an instance of that class that you need to create in that function.

Comment: When the return type is int, you have to return an int. When the return type is String you have to return a String. With a return type of Practice, you have to return a Practive object.

Comment: @backbrandt you *can* create the object in that method, but it is *not mandatory.* You can also return an already existing object (e.g. `this` or `someAttribute`) or `null`.

Comment: Please read some basics about class and object in java.

Comment: Before posting a Question here, learn the basics of Java by studying the free-of-cost tutorials by Oracle such as [*Returning a Value from a Method*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type would be an Object of type Practice. Or in other words, an instance of the class Practice.

Normally, you would create such an instance by using a constructor.

E.g. using the default constructor: `return new Practice();`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally an object of that specific class like this :

```
class Test 
{
    public Practice testFunction()
    {
        return new Practice();
    }
}
```